# Meta analysis in R with adjusted ORs

Tags: r

I would like to calculate a summary odds ratio value for two or more papers where the only information I have is the individual odds ratios with their 95% confidence intervals. Is this possible? I have been poking around in the meta package, and only figured out how to do it with crude counts.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome to SO. As written, your question is not a good fit for SO. If you were stuck coding (e.g., an error message did not understand), SO would be the place for you. However, you're asking us what statistical method to use and your post does not include any code. With editing, you might be able to post your question on Cross Validated to figure out what method to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite simple.

You just need to use the natural logarithm of the odds ratio (logOR), and its standard errror (and corresponding variance). These can be easily back-calculated from the 95% confidence intervals according to the normal distribution. Finally, pool logORs with their variance.

For instance, after you have built a data frame (eg called mydata) with logOR and variance for each study, you can easily proceed with a random effect meta-analysis with the `metafor` package in R as follows:

```
res <- rma(logOR, variance, data=mydata, method="DL")
forest(res)
```

In the future, you may consider posting similar questions in [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I didn't see this until now, but it is pretty much what I ended up doing. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to upvote/flag the answer as appropriate.

Comment: I tried to upvote, but I don't have enough points :( . But I did flag it, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Not to worry... again, look at CrossValidated as well for good hints on meta-analysis